# Html table rows width varies because of content

Tags: html, css

I am making a table as shown below. The problem is that when content of cells exceed then row length varies.Like you can see the difference in row 9 and row 10. **Width of all the rows must be same.** I can not give fixed width of column. As i don't know what will be the length of actual row.

One more thing i am using horizontal and vertical scroll. [JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/devender24391/knfm1xmv/1/).

```css
.container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    max-height: 396px;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-left: 5px;
    /* table-layout: fixed; */
    /* width: 100%; */
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="main_btl_container" style="width: 500px;position: relative;padding: 0px;border: 1px solid black;"><div style="opacity: 0; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1px; height: 166650px;"></div><table><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 0px;"><td>row 0  : col0</td><td>row 0  : col1</td><td>row 0  : col2</td><td>row 0  : col3</td><td>row 0  : col4</td><td>row 0  : col5</td><td>row 0  : col6</td><td>row 0  : col7</td><td>row 0  : col8</td><td>row 0  : col9</td><td>row 0  : col10</td><td>row 0  : col11</td><td>row 0  : col12</td><td>row 0  : col13</td><td>row 0  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 30px;"><td>row 1  : col0</td><td>row 1  : col1</td><td>row 1  : col2</td><td>row 1  : col3</td><td>row 1  : col4</td><td>row 1  : col5</td><td>row 1  : col6</td><td>row 1  : col7</td><td>row 1  : col8</td><td>row 1  : col9</td><td>row 1  : col10</td><td>row 1  : col11</td><td>row 1  : col12</td><td>row 1  : col13</td><td>row 1  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 60px;"><td>row 2  : col0</td><td>row 2  : col1</td><td>row 2  : col2</td><td>row 2  : col3</td><td>row 2  : col4</td><td>row 2  : col5</td><td>row 2  : col6</td><td>row 2  : col7</td><td>row 2  : col8</td><td>row 2  : col9</td><td>row 2  : col10</td><td>row 2  : col11</td><td>row 2  : col12</td><td>row 2  : col13</td><td>row 2  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 90px;"><td>row 3  : col0</td><td>row 3  : col1</td><td>row 3  : col2</td><td>row 3  : col3</td><td>row 3  : col4</td><td>row 3  : col5</td><td>row 3  : col6</td><td>row 3  : col7</td><td>row 3  : col8</td><td>row 3  : col9</td><td>row 3  : col10</td><td>row 3  : col11</td><td>row 3  : col12</td><td>row 3  : col13</td><td>row 3  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 120px;"><td>row 4  : col0</td><td>row 4  : col1</td><td>row 4  : col2</td><td>row 4  : col3</td><td>row 4  : col4</td><td>row 4  : col5</td><td>row 4  : col6</td><td>row 4  : col7</td><td>row 4  : col8</td><td>row 4  : col9</td><td>row 4  : col10</td><td>row 4  : col11</td><td>row 4  : col12</td><td>row 4  : col13</td><td>row 4  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 150px;"><td>row 5  : col0</td><td>row 5  : col1</td><td>row 5  : col2</td><td>row 5  : col3</td><td>row 5  : col4</td><td>row 5  : col5</td><td>row 5  : col6</td><td>row 5  : col7</td><td>row 5  : col8</td><td>row 5  : col9</td><td>row 5  : col10</td><td>row 5  : col11</td><td>row 5  : col12</td><td>row 5  : col13</td><td>row 5  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 180px;"><td>row 6  : col0</td><td>row 6  : col1</td><td>row 6  : col2</td><td>row 6  : col3</td><td>row 6  : col4</td><td>row 6  : col5</td><td>row 6  : col6</td><td>row 6  : col7</td><td>row 6  : col8</td><td>row 6  : col9</td><td>row 6  : col10</td><td>row 6  : col11</td><td>row 6  : col12</td><td>row 6  : col13</td><td>row 6  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 210px;"><td>row 7  : col0</td><td>row 7  : col1</td><td>row 7  : col2</td><td>row 7  : col3</td><td>row 7  : col4</td><td>row 7  : col5</td><td>row 7  : col6</td><td>row 7  : col7</td><td>row 7  : col8</td><td>row 7  : col9</td><td>row 7  : col10</td><td>row 7  : col11</td><td>row 7  : col12</td><td>row 7  : col13</td><td>row 7  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 240px;"><td>row 8  : col0</td><td>row 8  : col1</td><td>row 8  : col2</td><td>row 8  : col3</td><td>row 8  : col4</td><td>row 8  : col5</td><td>row 8  : col6</td><td>row 8  : col7</td><td>row 8  : col8</td><td>row 8  : col9</td><td>row 8  : col10</td><td>row 8  : col11</td><td>row 8  : col12</td><td>row 8  : col13</td><td>row 8  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 270px;"><td>row 9  : col0</td><td>row 9  : col1</td><td>row 9  : col2</td><td>row 9  : col3</td><td>row 9  : col4</td><td>row 9  : col5</td><td>row 9  : col6</td><td>row 9  : col7</td><td>row 9  : col8</td><td>row 9  : col9</td><td>row 9  : col10</td><td>row 9  : col11</td><td>row 9  : col12</td><td>row 9  : col13</td><td>row 9  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 300px;"><td>row 10  : col0</td><td>row 10  : col1</td><td>row 10  : col2</td><td>row 10  : col3</td><td>row 10  : col4</td><td>row 10  : col5</td><td>row 10  : col6</td><td>row 10  : col7</td><td>row 10  : col8</td><td>row 10  : col9</td><td>row 10  : col10</td><td>row 10  : col11</td><td>row 10  : col12</td><td>row 10  : col13</td><td>row 10  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 330px;"><td>row 11  : col0</td><td>row 11  : col1</td><td>row 11  : col2</td><td>row 11  : col3</td><td>row 11  : col4</td><td>row 11  : col5</td><td>row 11  : col6</td><td>row 11  : col7</td><td>row 11  : col8</td><td>row 11  : col9</td><td>row 11  : col10</td><td>row 11  : col11</td><td>row 11  : col12</td><td>row 11  : col13</td><td>row 11  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 360px;"><td>row 12  : col0</td><td>row 12  : col1</td><td>row 12  : col2</td><td>row 12  : col3</td><td>row 12  : col4</td><td>row 12  : col5</td><td>row 12  : col6</td><td>row 12  : col7</td><td>row 12  : col8</td><td>row 12  : col9</td><td>row 12  : col10</td><td>row 12  : col11</td><td>row 12  : col12</td><td>row 12  : col13</td><td>row 12  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 390px;"><td>row 13  : col0</td><td>row 13  : col1</td><td>row 13  : col2</td><td>row 13  : col3</td><td>row 13  : col4</td><td>row 13  : col5</td><td>row 13  : col6</td><td>row 13  : col7</td><td>row 13  : col8</td><td>row 13  : col9</td><td>row 13  : col10</td><td>row 13  : col11</td><td>row 13  : col12</td><td>row 13  : col13</td><td>row 13  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 420px;"><td>row 14  : col0</td><td>row 14  : col1</td><td>row 14  : col2</td><td>row 14  : col3</td><td>row 14  : col4</td><td>row 14  : col5</td><td>row 14  : col6</td><td>row 14  : col7</td><td>row 14  : col8</td><td>row 14  : col9</td><td>row 14  : col10</td><td>row 14  : col11</td><td>row 14  : col12</td><td>row 14  : col13</td><td>row 14  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 450px;"><td>row 15  : col0</td><td>row 15  : col1</td><td>row 15  : col2</td><td>row 15  : col3</td><td>row 15  : col4</td><td>row 15  : col5</td><td>row 15  : col6</td><td>row 15  : col7</td><td>row 15  : col8</td><td>row 15  : col9</td><td>row 15  : col10</td><td>row 15  : col11</td><td>row 15  : col12</td><td>row 15  : col13</td><td>row 15  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 480px;"><td>row 16  : col0</td><td>row 16  : col1</td><td>row 16  : col2</td><td>row 16  : col3</td><td>row 16  : col4</td><td>row 16  : col5</td><td>row 16  : col6</td><td>row 16  : col7</td><td>row 16  : col8</td><td>row 16  : col9</td><td>row 16  : col10</td><td>row 16  : col11</td><td>row 16  : col12</td><td>row 16  : col13</td><td>row 16  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 510px;"><td>row 17  : col0</td><td>row 17  : col1</td><td>row 17  : col2</td><td>row 17  : col3</td><td>row 17  : col4</td><td>row 17  : col5</td><td>row 17  : col6</td><td>row 17  : col7</td><td>row 17  : col8</td><td>row 17  : col9</td><td>row 17  : col10</td><td>row 17  : col11</td><td>row 17  : col12</td><td>row 17  : col13</td><td>row 17  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 540px;"><td>row 18  : col0</td><td>row 18  : col1</td><td>row 18  : col2</td><td>row 18  : col3</td><td>row 18  : col4</td><td>row 18  : col5</td><td>row 18  : col6</td><td>row 18  : col7</td><td>row 18  : col8</td><td>row 18  : col9</td><td>row 18  : col10</td><td>row 18  : col11</td><td>row 18  : col12</td><td>row 18  : col13</td><td>row 18  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 570px;"><td>row 19  : col0</td><td>row 19  : col1</td><td>row 19  : col2</td><td>row 19  : col3</td><td>row 19  : col4</td><td>row 19  : col5</td><td>row 19  : col6</td><td>row 19  : col7</td><td>row 19  : col8</td><td>row 19  : col9</td><td>row 19  : col10</td><td>row 19  : col11</td><td>row 19  : col12</td><td>row 19  : col13</td><td>row 19  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 600px;"><td>row 20  : col0</td><td>row 20  : col1</td><td>row 20  : col2</td><td>row 20  : col3</td><td>row 20  : col4</td><td>row 20  : col5</td><td>row 20  : col6</td><td>row 20  : col7</td><td>row 20  : col8</td><td>row 20  : col9</td><td>row 20  : col10</td><td>row 20  : col11</td><td>row 20  : col12</td><td>row 20  : col13</td><td>row 20  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 630px;"><td>row 21  : col0</td><td>row 21  : col1</td><td>row 21  : col2</td><td>row 21  : col3</td><td>row 21  : col4</td><td>row 21  : col5</td><td>row 21  : col6</td><td>row 21  : col7</td><td>row 21  : col8</td><td>row 21  : col9</td><td>row 21  : col10</td><td>row 21  : col11</td><td>row 21  : col12</td><td>row 21  : col13</td><td>row 21  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 660px;"><td>row 22  : col0</td><td>row 22  : col1</td><td>row 22  : col2</td><td>row 22  : col3</td><td>row 22  : col4</td><td>row 22  : col5</td><td>row 22  : col6</td><td>row 22  : col7</td><td>row 22  : col8</td><td>row 22  : col9</td><td>row 22  : col10</td><td>row 22  : col11</td><td>row 22  : col12</td><td>row 22  : col13</td><td>row 22  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 690px;"><td>row 23  : col0</td><td>row 23  : col1</td><td>row 23  : col2</td><td>row 23  : col3</td><td>row 23  : col4</td><td>row 23  : col5</td><td>row 23  : col6</td><td>row 23  : col7</td><td>row 23  : col8</td><td>row 23  : col9</td><td>row 23  : col10</td><td>row 23  : col11</td><td>row 23  : col12</td><td>row 23  : col13</td><td>row 23  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 720px;"><td>row 24  : col0</td><td>row 24  : col1</td><td>row 24  : col2</td><td>row 24  : col3</td><td>row 24  : col4</td><td>row 24  : col5</td><td>row 24  : col6</td><td>row 24  : col7</td><td>row 24  : col8</td><td>row 24  : col9</td><td>row 24  : col10</td><td>row 24  : col11</td><td>row 24  : col12</td><td>row 24  : col13</td><td>row 24  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 750px;"><td>row 25  : col0</td><td>row 25  : col1</td><td>row 25  : col2</td><td>row 25  : col3</td><td>row 25  : col4</td><td>row 25  : col5</td><td>row 25  : col6</td><td>row 25  : col7</td><td>row 25  : col8</td><td>row 25  : col9</td><td>row 25  : col10</td><td>row 25  : col11</td><td>row 25  : col12</td><td>row 25  : col13</td><td>row 25  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 780px;"><td>row 26  : col0</td><td>row 26  : col1</td><td>row 26  : col2</td><td>row 26  : col3</td><td>row 26  : col4</td><td>row 26  : col5</td><td>row 26  : col6</td><td>row 26  : col7</td><td>row 26  : col8</td><td>row 26  : col9</td><td>row 26  : col10</td><td>row 26  : col11</td><td>row 26  : col12</td><td>row 26  : col13</td><td>row 26  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 810px;"><td>row 27  : col0</td><td>row 27  : col1</td><td>row 27  : col2</td><td>row 27  : col3</td><td>row 27  : col4</td><td>row 27  : col5</td><td>row 27  : col6</td><td>row 27  : col7</td><td>row 27  : col8</td><td>row 27  : col9</td><td>row 27  : col10</td><td>row 27  : col11</td><td>row 27  : col12</td><td>row 27  : col13</td><td>row 27  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 840px;"><td>row 28  : col0</td><td>row 28  : col1</td><td>row 28  : col2</td><td>row 28  : col3</td><td>row 28  : col4</td><td>row 28  : col5</td><td>row 28  : col6</td><td>row 28  : col7</td><td>row 28  : col8</td><td>row 28  : col9</td><td>row 28  : col10</td><td>row 28  : col11</td><td>row 28  : col12</td><td>row 28  : col13</td><td>row 28  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 870px;"><td>row 29  : col0</td><td>row 29  : col1</td><td>row 29  : col2</td><td>row 29  : col3</td><td>row 29  : col4</td><td>row 29  : col5</td><td>row 29  : col6</td><td>row 29  : col7</td><td>row 29  : col8</td><td>row 29  : col9</td><td>row 29  : col10</td><td>row 29  : col11</td><td>row 29  : col12</td><td>row 29  : col13</td><td>row 29  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 900px;"><td>row 30  : col0</td><td>row 30  : col1</td><td>row 30  : col2</td><td>row 30  : col3</td><td>row 30  : col4</td><td>row 30  : col5</td><td>row 30  : col6</td><td>row 30  : col7</td><td>row 30  : col8</td><td>row 30  : col9</td><td>row 30  : col10</td><td>row 30  : col11</td><td>row 30  : col12</td><td>row 30  : col13</td><td>row 30  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 930px;"><td>row 31  : col0</td><td>row 31  : col1</td><td>row 31  : col2</td><td>row 31  : col3</td><td>row 31  : col4</td><td>row 31  : col5</td><td>row 31  : col6</td><td>row 31  : col7</td><td>row 31  : col8</td><td>row 31  : col9</td><td>row 31  : col10</td><td>row 31  : col11</td><td>row 31  : col12</td><td>row 31  : col13</td><td>row 31  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 960px;"><td>row 32  : col0</td><td>row 32  : col1</td><td>row 32  : col2</td><td>row 32  : col3</td><td>row 32  : col4</td><td>row 32  : col5</td><td>row 32  : col6</td><td>row 32  : col7</td><td>row 32  : col8</td><td>row 32  : col9</td><td>row 32  : col10</td><td>row 32  : col11</td><td>row 32  : col12</td><td>row 32  : col13</td><td>row 32  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 990px;"><td>row 33  : col0</td><td>row 33  : col1</td><td>row 33  : col2</td><td>row 33  : col3</td><td>row 33  : col4</td><td>row 33  : col5</td><td>row 33  : col6</td><td>row 33  : col7</td><td>row 33  : col8</td><td>row 33  : col9</td><td>row 33  : col10</td><td>row 33  : col11</td><td>row 33  : col12</td><td>row 33  : col13</td><td>row 33  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 1020px;"><td>row 34  : col0</td><td>row 34  : col1</td><td>row 34  : col2</td><td>row 34  : col3</td><td>row 34  : col4</td><td>row 34  : col5</td><td>row 34  : col6</td><td>row 34  : col7</td><td>row 34  : col8</td><td>row 34  : col9</td><td>row 34  : col10</td><td>row 34  : col11</td><td>row 34  : col12</td><td>row 34  : col13</td><td>row 34  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 1050px;"><td>row 35  : col0</td><td>row 35  : col1</td><td>row 35  : col2</td><td>row 35  : col3</td><td>row 35  : col4</td><td>row 35  : col5</td><td>row 35  : col6</td><td>row 35  : col7</td><td>row 35  : col8</td><td>row 35  : col9</td><td>row 35  : col10</td><td>row 35  : col11</td><td>row 35  : col12</td><td>row 35  : col13</td><td>row 35  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 1080px;"><td>row 36  : col0</td><td>row 36  : col1</td><td>row 36  : col2</td><td>row 36  : col3</td><td>row 36  : col4</td><td>row 36  : col5</td><td>row 36  : col6</td><td>row 36  : col7</td><td>row 36  : col8</td><td>row 36  : col9</td><td>row 36  : col10</td><td>row 36  : col11</td><td>row 36  : col12</td><td>row 36  : col13</td><td>row 36  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 1110px;"><td>row 37  : col0</td><td>row 37  : col1</td><td>row 37  : col2</td><td>row 37  : col3</td><td>row 37  : col4</td><td>row 37  : col5</td><td>row 37  : col6</td><td>row 37  : col7</td><td>row 37  : col8</td><td>row 37  : col9</td><td>row 37  : col10</td><td>row 37  : col11</td><td>row 37  : col12</td><td>row 37  : col13</td><td>row 37  : col14</td></tr><tr class="vrow" style="position: absolute; top: 1140px;"><td>row 38  : col0</td><td>row 38  : col1</td><td>row 38  : col2</td><td>row 38  : col3</td><td>row 38  : col4</td><td>row 38  : col5</td><td>row 38  : col6</td><td>row 38  : col7</td><td>row 38  : col8</td><td>row 38  : col9</td><td>row 38  : col10</td><td>row 38  : col11</td><td>row 38  : col12</td><td>row 38  : col13</td><td>row 38  : col14</td></tr></table></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Use "max-width" property

Comment: It does not work. I have tried it.

Comment: use another one     word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: I can not use that because i need to show content of cell without breaking it. This is just sample. In originally cell content could be a text field or a button or anything else.

Comment: @Devender Kumar,  try min-width in td tag, see my answer . i hope you need this.

Answer (score 0):

Use max-width,

```
 table, th, td {
     white-space: pre-line;
     max-width: 200px; //use whatever you want
     overflow-x: hidden;
     word-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `position: absolute;` on each row (`<tr>`) and why do you have something like `height: 166650px;` set for your container class?

Try to omit that and it will just be good. However you may want to tweak also other styles. Simplicity should be the key.

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j82gkhbq/)

Answer (score 0):

### Changes

- Remove all `position` properties.
- Move the huge 16k div below the table.
- Give all `<td>` height of 26.8px which should compute to about 30px.
- Make `.container`'s dimensions `min-width: 500px` and `min-height: 398px`. Why would it need to limit itself to way less in length of it's content(ie table) if it is a container?

Having `absolute` and `relative` on table components is a hindrance to a table in general because a table's components' positions are already determined more or less. Imposing `absolute` on `<tr>` will most likely break the table (as we see in the question's example).

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/zvtw08ds/)